# Visual Studio IDE freezing while initializing ToolBox

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm working on Visual Studio 2008, Smart Client + infragistics controls are installed and we have more than 50 User Controls. When opening the Visual Studio "Tool Box", Visual Studio is completely freezing. I couldn't work after that. I have to kill the process and open again. At this point CPU usage is around 50, CPU usage is 1 or 2 when i work on code. How to get rid out of this issue. This is really time consuming process.

Comment: I disabled the AutoToolboxPopulate feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

[Visual Studio 2008 takes a long time to open the toolbox for a solution that contains many custom controls](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973462)

The KB article recommends downloading and installing a hotfix.